# Не могли бы мне помочь определить, являются ли определения однородными?

Tags: синтаксис

Являются ли однородными определения в предложении: "Мокрые тяжелые грозди душистой сирени от влаги к земле клонятся". Не от того ли грозди тяжёлые, что мокрые?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Мокрые, тяжелые** грозди душистой сирени от влаги к земле клонятся.*

Да, все верно, в заданном контексте имеет место **сближение** разных признаков (мокрый и тяжелый) по **причинно-следственной** связи между ними: грозди склоняются, так как они намокли и стали тяжелыми.

**[По Розенталю](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98)** это пункт 1(3): определения однородны, если в условиях **контекста**, характеризуя предмет с **разных** сторон, **объединяются** каким-либо **общим** признаком (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, **причинно-следственной** связью и т. д.):